# XMLHttpRequest cannot load url Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 in angularjs and mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, ionic-framework

Hi Im using angularjs and mongodb for my app. When Im trying to delete the selected item from the list Im getting the error stating `XMLHttpRequest cannot load url Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`.I even went through lot of tech-forums, what I understood was, it is caused due to the cross-origin resource sharing. But I couldn't find the reason why it is caused or what is causing it. So I'm looking for your help in understanding it. Thanks you.

Comment: You are probably doing call to other domain or port, which cause first request to be options, and your server returns 404 error.

Comment: But my domain is same as the other api

Comment: Can you please add more details which URL you are on and which url you are making request, best would be if you post screen.

Comment: This is CORS issue.

Comment: Is there any solution to this @Bik